# ARM M4F Debug-Output

Tags: arm, swd, swo

Currently I am working on a space/pin-constraint project. The software is run on a ARM M4F (MAX32660 MCU) [Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/max32660-user-guide.pdf).

I have connected the MCU to my Dev-Machine via a Segger J-Link [J-Link Debug probe](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/) through the SWD-Port.

I am using Eclipse CDT C/C++ [Eclispe CDT C/C++](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.cdt).

**My question:**

Is it possible to send custom data via the SWD interface and show it in a Eclipse "Console-Like" window? I am okay with MCU-To-Eclipse Data-Direction and standard CMSIS Libs, as well as self-coded.

I am thinking about:

```
void SWD_Write(u32 data){ /* magic */ }

.....
if ( ... ){ SWD_Write( .... ); }
.....
```

Which results in a text-output (Best with timestamps, but not an issue if none available). It must be possible to export the text (either manual copy/paste or piped to file).

**What I have researched so far:**

- I read about the ITM [Article about ARM ITM](https://percepio.com/arm-itm/) Peripheral. But sadly, I cant use it as it requires a SWO pin - which is not available on my MCU.
- Currently I am using stack variables and assigning values to them. I then hover the mouse and read the value from the Eclipse Debug GUI. **This is not what I want!**

Comment: Since you're using a Segger J-Link, you might consider using [Ozone](https://www.segger.com/products/development-tools/ozone-j-link-debugger/technology/application-debugging/) to debug instead of Eclipse. That will allow you to use Segger's "RTT" to perform printf-like operations over SWD from the MCU to a console window in the Ozone debugger application.

Comment: You seem to be looking for *semihosting*.

Comment: @brhans According to https://www.segger.com/products/development-tools/ozone-j-link-debugger/technology/application-debugging/ "Ozone handles/works with Single Wire Output (SWO). On Cortex-M microcontrollers an additional pin on the debug interface, the SWO pin, can be used to send terminal output to the debugger" the SWO pins is required - which is not available. Or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: Hmmm - good question ... I know I've used Ozone on a project without SWO, but I can't remember if I used RTT at the same time.

Comment: @brhans Okay. Thank you for the information though! I downloaded to app for eval purposes and it looks great! Did not know about it yet, so thank you very much!

Comment: You might also consider [Crossworks](https://www.rowley.co.uk/crossworks/Evaluating.htm) instead of Eclipse for both developing & debugging - it offers similar printf-like functionality (through <__cross_studio_io.h>) and (as far as I remember) doesn't have any particular debugger requirements. It's not free, but you get 30 days of full-functionality evaluation or an unlimited time 16kB code size limit.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Is this the Semihosting you mentioned? https://mcuoneclipse.com/2023/03/09/using-semihosting-the-direct-way/

Comment: Yes. Not sure it is the best resource though, but looks quite comprehensive